# SQL Where ANY column equals a value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible in MySQL to select all rows where ANY column contains a specified value?

I'm trying to write a generic search function that can work without any information about a table schema.

Comment: DBAs everywhere will hate you.

Comment: What is the type of the value?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl` will work every time, but it won't exclude rows that don't match. :)

Comment: @GordonBell Because he is rogue coder!

Comment: Fulltext search [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: @Val, with FULLTEXT you have to name the columns when you add the index and in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) to get a list of the columns in the table and then dynamically build your query from the results.