# How to search in all columns of a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am using this code to find out if there is a field in the column "website" that matches `$string`:

```
$get_results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
     "SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE website LIKE %s LIMIT 10", 
     "%{$wpdb->esc_like($string)}%"
));
```

This works but I would like to figure out if there is a field in ANY COLUMN that matches $string.

I thought I could just use `WHERE *` but this is not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656529/sql-where-any-column-equals-a-value (basically it's getting the column list and then building the query using that)

Comment: you can export the database and search through it using a text editor, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350088/how-to-search-a-specific-value-in-all-tables-postgresql/5350405#5350405).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only place a "wildcard" for specifying fields is allowed is in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found myself a solution:

```
$get_results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM yc_customers WHERE website LIKE %s OR receiver LIKE %s OR email LIKE %s LIMIT 10",
        "%{$wpdb->esc_like($string)}%",
        "%{$wpdb->esc_like($string)}%",
        "%{$wpdb->esc_like($string)}%"
));
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question really. It is manually addressing every column that you want to search in.